# How can I filter out results based on another table. (A reverse join I guess?)

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Basically, I have a table which contains two fields: `[id, other]` which have user tokens stored in them. The goal of my query is to select a random user that has not been selected before. Once the user is selected it is stored in the table shown above. So if Jack selects Jim randomly, Jack cannot select Jim again, and on the flip side, Jim cannot select Jack.

Something like this is what comes to mind:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE (SELECT * FROM selected WHERE (id=? AND other=?) OR (id=? AND other=?));
```

Well, first of all I've read that uses sub-queries like this is extremely inneficient, and I'm not even sure if I used the correct syntax, the problem is however, that I have numerous tables in my scenario which I need to filter by, so it would look more like this.

```
SELECT * FROM users u
WHERE (SELECT * FROM selected WHERE (id=? AND other=?) OR (id=? AND other=?))
AND (SELECT * FROM other_table WHERE (id=? AND other=?) OR (id=? AND other=?))
AND (SELECT * FROM diff_table WHERE (id=? AND value=?))
AND u.type = 'BASIC'
LIMIT = 1
```

I feel like there's a much, much more efficient way of handling this.

Please note: I don't want a row returned at all if the users id is present in any of the nested queries. Returning "null" is not sufficient. The reason I have the `OR` clause is because the user's id can be stored in either the `id` or the `other` field, so we need to check both.

**I am using Postgre 9.5.3, but I added the MySQL tag as the code is mostly backwards comptable, Fancy Postgre only solutions are accepted(if any)**

Comment: Are you actually trying to select a (new) random pairing?  It's one thing to say "pick a new unique random partner for Jack" but another to say "pick two random people who have never been paired before"

Comment: What you need seems to be `[not] EXISTS(subquery)` , presumably correlated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can left join to another table, which produces nulls where no record is found:

```
Select u.* from users u
left selected s on s.id = u.id or s.other = u.other
where s.id is null
```

The or in a join is different, but should work.  Example is kinda silly...but as long as you understand the logic.  Left join first table to second table, where second table column is not null means there was atleast one record found that matched the join conditions.  Where second table column is null means no record was found.

And you are right...avoid the where field = (select statement) logic when you can, poor performer there.

Answer (score 1):

Use an outer join filtered on missed joins:

```
SELECT * FROM users u
LEFT JOIN selected s on u.id in (s.id, s.other) and ? in (s.id, s.other)
WHERE u.id != ?
AND s.id IN NULL
LIMIT 1
```